# Spacify width for each tab in android tab bar

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-widget

Hi i have to develop one tab bar  example.here i have to **set the width for each tab**.because i wish to set the **first tab width is larger**.the **second tab width is small**.how can i develop.please help me.

This is my code part:

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:tabStripEnabled="false"

          android:background="@drawable/tabicon" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  </TabHost>
```

**TabBar.java:**

```
public class TabBarSimple extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    TabSpec dbspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("DashBoard"); 
    dbspec.setIndicator("Dashboard", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dashboard));


    Intent dbIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
    dbspec.setContent(dbIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(dbspec);

    TabSpec orderspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Orders");
    orderspec.setIndicator("Orders", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.orders));

    Intent orderIntent = new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class);
    orderspec.setContent(orderIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(orderspec);

    }
```

}

Here How can i set my width on each tab.

Answer (score 2):

May be this will help

```
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height));
```

where width and height are the desired size for that tab.

You would need to repeat this for every tab via calls to appropriate indexes of getChildAt().

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_weight` to give this type of look of perticular Tab.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, instead of directly setting the drawables as indicators, you can create separate xmls with ImageViews, inflate them into a View and set the View as indicator. By this, you can set different widths for the 3 ImageViews.

TabBar.java

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.indicator_view_db,null);
dbspec.setIndicator(view);
```

indicator_view_db.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dashboard"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this way, you can have separate xmls for dashboard and orders.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin Developer

```
AddView(_tabLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent));
```